# React Native: How to include third-party JS file?

Tags: javascript, react-native, sdk

Is there a way to include or load external script into React Native? I need to adjust Web SDK for React Native?

Comment: Which platform are you trying to targeting? Web?
Are you using react-native-web?

Comment: I'm targeting mobile (React Native), need to use web SDK for React Native. In Web we append script to window, how can we do that in RN?

Comment: Basically, you cannot, since everything has to be built and packaged. It's also one of the requirements of app stores.
In general, you can use npm or yarn to fetch external code to your project, and import in code when you need it. So the external codes will be packaged in your .apk/.ipa.

Comment: You can use react-native-webview in some parts of your app though, and treat that part as a web app.